# Solving the error 'Multipart object with only one feature'

Tags: qgis

I have a single feature county boundary shp file, and when I run Check Geometries on it it says 'Error - Multipart object with only one feature'. However when I ask QGIS to fix this it takes no action.  The same if I run 'Fix Geometries' from the processing toolbox. Does this error matter if, say, I run any functions using this border as an overlay and if so how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you share that single feature county boundary shape?

Comment: The shapefile format does not separate polygons and multipolygons like some other formats do. A polygon shapefile can contain multipolygons but it is OK to have simple polygons or a mixture of  polygons and multipolygons. The error seems to be false positive and you cannot fix the geometry because it is not wrong.